# Удаление моего предварительно закрытого вопроса

Tags: поддержка, удаление-вопросов

Некоторое время назад я разбирался с некой проблемой, и создал вопрос на ruSO.

Мне по этому вопросу дали ответ и написали ряд ценных комментариев.

Через некоторое время вопрос был закрыт, по-моему, из-за "отсутствия воспроизводимого примера неработающего кода", хотя вообще пример кода там присутствовал.

Сейчас я увидел, что вопрос удален, причем среди моих "недавно удаленных" его нет.

У меня есть субъективное ощущение, что комментарии к этому вопросу для меня представляют ценность. Нельзя ли мне его хотя бы на время вернуть, чтобы я скопировал локально инфу оттуда?

Ключевые слова - C++, libssl

Comment: Единственный твой удалённый вопрос [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1185522/178988), но его никогда не закрывали, а удалён он был тобой. Речь точно о вопросе, а не об ответе?

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за подсказку. я нашел то, что искал: c++ - OpenSSL под Windows (используя g++ и MSYS2) - не могу собрать проект - Stack Overflow на русском
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176381/openssl-под-windows-используя-g-и-msys2-не-могу-собрать-проект/1176417#1176417

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свои удалённые сообщения (как вопросы так и ответы) вы всегда можете найти, используя параметры поиска `user:me deleted:1`. Готовая ссылка для ruSO: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=User%3Ame+deleted%3A1

Как оказалось (надо было просто вспомнить), поиск по удалённым собственным сообщениям работает только если у вас есть 10 тыс репутации на сайте.

Есть старый вопрос на MSE [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted), в котором отклонили возможность показывать список удалённых вопросов пользователя без ограничений репутации. Но это было очень давно, и по моему мнению стоит пересмотреть его. Голосуйте. Вдруг достижение 1000 голосов что-то да значит для сотрудников Stack Overflow.

Comment: Этот поиск не работает если нет 10К репутации.

Comment: @Qwertiy как молоды мы были. На всякий случай объявил [конкурс](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/339911), хотя вряд ли что-то изменится.

Answer (score 2):

Если вопрос был удален недавно (**в течение 60 дней**), то можно его найти с помощью ссылки **"недавно удаленные вопросы"**: Профиль -> Активность -> Вопросы.

Эта ссылка вида

> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/XXXX

где XXXX — ID участника, доступна всем, без ограничений по репутации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Источник с Общей Меты](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130286/383809).

Comment: Кстати, ТС явно пишет, что *"причем среди моих "недавно удаленных" его нет"*

Comment: @αλεχολυτ надел очки, прочитал ТС, снял очки. Когда я писал ответ, тот абзац скрылся от меня аки в тумане милая Одесса. Ну пусть висит, може когда на него тоже можно будет сослаться...