# Как снять вечный бан на вопросы на английском StackOverflow?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

На StackOverflow (английской версии сайта) я задал вопрос, как мне казалось достаточно корректный.

Я задал вопрос по вопросам реализации, а не конкретно по коду. Модератором вопрос показался не "конкретный", хотя конкретики я не мог добавить по причине того, что я её и не знал. Я как раз-таки спрашивал про технический вопрос к проблеме.

Из-за чего я получил -10 репутации и вопрос был закрыт. Т.к. вопрос был закрыт я решил его удалить.

И теперь я физически не могу дополнить вопрос.

Я пытался отвечать на вопросы, помогать и даже поднял свою репутацию на английском СтакОферфлоу.

Но бан не снимается. Я написал в поддержку - поддержка молчит

Что можете посоветовать или же сказать по этому поводу?

Comment: Ну, во-первых, найди тот вопрос. Вот так: `user:11563491 delete:1`.

Comment: Во-вторых через пол года вам должны дать "второй шанс" ;)

Comment: В третьих ну к черту это их большое SO — это готовая база данных, так что задать вопрос не дупликат там надо постараться ;). Участвуйте тут ;)

Comment: Ваши удалённые вопросы: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A11745788+deleted%3A1+)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Тот вопрос уже не подлежит восстановлению и модерации.
Обидно, я не хочу ждать пол года(

Comment: @vp_arth выяснили, что это [не работает](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11063/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0#comment46800_11064) без 10к реп.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, странно, ведь даже после 10к поиск выдаёт только свои сообщения. Непонятно, зачем такое ограничение. =)

Comment: -10 дают не модераторы, а простые пользователи. видимо что-то совсем не понравилось тамошним блюстителям морали и нравственности

Comment: Я получил бан, после этого вопроса
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984207/testing-streaming-service-like-selenium
Если не сложно, то можете поднять его, хотя бы в 0, чтобы бан спал(

Comment: Ну как? ;).....

Comment: Благодарю, это помогло!